# Editing Theme In Existing Drupal Site

Tags: installation, theming

I work at a non-profit, and the person in charge of the website has left.  I have taught myself how to edit the website online through our web log in, but can't figure out how to edit the theme.  All I need to do is add a logo to the theme (we use the Zen subtheme).  Is this something I can even do online, or do I need to set up a server shell or server test site on my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to /admin/appearance/settings/YOUR_THEME_NAME and scroll to the bottom and find the logo field and upload your custom logo

See the following for a nice visual walkthrough.

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/customize-theme/upload-custom-logo

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is, I need to add a logo to the one already on the site.  When I go to the "configure" page under the main theme we use, it only allows one logo.  I also don't have Drupal installed anywhere, and am trying to see if I can do all of this online with my web login.

Comment: It won't allow you to add a second logo. The best thing to do is to create an new image using both logos and replace the single logo. Or disable the log and replace it with a block where you can upload two images. ps. Drupal is already installed, that is what your website is. There is no drupal software that you have to install on your local machine to "administer the site".